# Regex to find embedded quotes in a quotes string

Tags: c#

Original string:

> 11235485|56987|0|2010|05|"This is my sample
>   "text""|"01J400B"|""|1|"Sample "text" number two"|""sample text number
>   three""|""|""|

Desired string:

> 11235485|56987|0|2010|05|"This is my sample
>   ""text"""|"01J400B"|""|1|"Sample ""text"" number two"|"""sample text
>   number three"""|""|""|

The desired string unfortunately is a requirement that is out of my control, all nested quotes MUST be qualified with quotes (I KNOW).

Try as I might I have not been able to create the desired string from the original.

A regex match/replace seems to be the way to go, I need help.  Any help is appreciated.

Comment: While it is possible to do this with many regex flavors, this kind of input doesn't meet the formal definition of "regular" text, meaning regex may not be your best choice.

Comment: The good news is that this isn't a new problem. You should be able to find a pre-written, battle-tested delimited text parser that knows how to handle this kind of error. It'll probably out-perform regex, too.

Comment: Take a look at [TextFieldParser Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.fileio.textfieldparser(v=vs.110).aspx) - It will handle quotes just fine.

Answer (score 1):

I'd actually split the string and evaluate each piece:

```
public string Escape(string input)
{
    string[] pieces = input.Split('|');

    for (int i = 0; i < pieces.Length; i++)
    {
        string piece = pieces[i];

        if (piece.StartsWith("\"") && piece.EndsWith("\""))
        {
            pieces[i] = "\"" + piece.Trim('\"').Replace("\"", "\"\"") + "\"";
        }
    }

    return string.Join("|", pieces);
}
```

This is making several assumptions about the input:

- Items are delimited by pipes (`|`)
- Items are well formed and will begin and end with quotation marks

This will also break if you have `|`s inside of quoted strings.

Comment: They would need to handle the logic to ignore the first and last quotations though. This would take "This is sample "test"" and return ""This is sample ""text"""", and she would need "This is sample ""text""". Just throw in a check that index of "\"" is not = 0 and "\"" is not `piece[1].length-1`.

Comment: What if a field can contain a pipe character inside the quotes that is not a column delimiter?

Comment: @HobbsBear: The `piece.Trim('\"')` bit should remove the leading and trailing `"` before attempting a replace

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn: I acknowledged that this solution will break in that case

Comment: This one works as well.  There will never be a | in the text.  That and other characters are checked at the door.

Answer (score 1):

You may be able to just use the normal `string.Replace()` method. You know that `|` is what starts the column, so you can replace all `"` to `""` and then fix the column start and end by replacing `|""` to `|"` and `""|` to `"|`.

It'd look like this:

```cs
var input = YOUR_ORIGINAL_STRING;
input.Replace("\"", "\"\"").Replace("|\"\"", "|\"").Replace("\"\"|", "\"|"));
```

It's not pretty, but it gets the job done.

Comment: What if a field can contain a pipe character inside the quotes that is not a column delimiter?

Comment: The replace statement will not mess with pipes inside of quotes so long as the pipe isn't the first or last  character inside the quotes (eg if you have `|"Hello this "example | won't " be touched" | 123`) but it will mess with `|" this "| will "| cause a problem "| 142`. However in that case you will have many more problems as you cannot tell where the field delimits and where the column does

Comment: You are right, not pretty, but it works.  Thank you!